# A question about automorphism and inner automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$\mathbb{Z}$  is a group under addition. I wish to find $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\text{Inn}(\mathbb{Z})$

I know the only automorphism groups of $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition are$\{f(x)=x, f(x)=-x\}$ but what about the inner atomorphisms $\text{Inn} (\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: ${\mathbb Z}$ is an abelian group.

Comment: @DerekHolt..yes Z is abelian group

Comment: If you know that, then it is not clear why you asking about its inner automorphism group.

Answer (score -1):

Refers [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156179/automorphism-on-integers), you can see what $Aut(\mathbb{Z})$ is.

And note that for the ring $R$, the inner automorphisms of R form a normal subgroup of the automorphism group of $R$.