# Endomorphisms and automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

How to indicate all the endomorphisms and automorphisms of $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$?

I know that endomorphism is a homomorphism from a certain group to itself and automorphism is an endomorphism which is also bijective. Therefore I can give some examples of endomorphisms such as $f(\mathbb{Z}) = n\mathbb{Z}$ or automorphisms like $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=-x$. I assume the automorphisms are connected to the generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ but I don't have anything to back it up with except from my intuition.

My problem is that I can't tell, not even mentioning proving, if the examples I thought of are the only existing endomorphisms and automorphisms of $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$.

Comment: Any group homomorphism must take the identity to the identity, so $f(0)=0$. Then, as you correctly guess, a group homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ into another group is completely determined by $f(1)$, because $f(n)=f(1+\dots+1)=f(1)+\dots+f(1)$ (using abelian notation). In other words, you can use the definition of a group homomorphism and a generator to prove that your intuition is correct, and I'd encourage you to do so.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156179/automorphism-on-integers) The two you thought of are the only possible automorphisms.

Comment: $f(\mathbb Z) = n \mathbb Z$ does not define a function. On the other hand, $f(k)=nk$ does.